# Jquery :gt(value) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got multiple  tags , but only one with class "active". I want to get that div index and store it into var. Also I want to tell jQuery to change the width of div's after the one with class active.

```
var active_container = $('active').index();/// Output: 3

$('container_div:gt(active_container)').css({'width':'10px'});
```

This should do the job but no luck.
P.S Sorry if the code is not visible but I am typing from phone(PC issues).Please redact it , so it can be more visible.

Comment: `active_container` is just a string in the jQuery selector. Escape it. `$('container_div:gt('+active_container+')')`

Comment: `$('.active')` instead of `$('active')` too

Comment: And `$('.container_div')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `active_container` is a variable, you need to concatenate it to the selector string. Something like:

`$('container_div:gt(' + active_container +' )').css({'width':'10px'})`;